# Elasticsearch query speed degrade

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch(1.5.2) cluster (2 node with data) with 218M docs (22.3Gi). All elastic setting by default (5 shard and 1 replica), except memory: -Xmx5g -Xms5g

My problem is that query request is very slow - 2sec. When index was small ~10K doc requery time was 100-200 ms. I'm running this with a load of 50 concurrent users and time increase up to 10-20 sec.

Cluster machines:
2 dedicated vm nodes

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU(s):                16
Core(s) per socket:    8
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
Memory:                16Gb
```

Mapping:

```
{
"all": {
    "properties": {
        "schemarev": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "schema": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "rev": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "properties": {
            "properties": {
                "фио": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "телефон": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "возраст": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "адрес": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "type": "nested"
        },
        "_creator_id": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "schemaid": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Document sample:

```
{
    "schemaId": "55eaf455-b0db-4359-95cd-b16b57ae7b3e",
    "name": "o1",
    "properties": {
        "фио": "asd",
        "телефон": "8967234",
        "адрес": "asfsdf",
        "возраст": 37
    }
}
```

Query like this, no aggregation:

```
{
    "match_all" : { }
}
```

this size=10 and from=0

Also in log there is:

```
[WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [Master Order] [gc][young][50][9] duration [1s], collections [1]/[1.6s], total [1s]/[1.9s], memory [4.3gb]->[4.2gb]/[9.8gb], all_pools {[young] [748.1mb]->[32.5mb]/[865.3mb]}{[survivor] [108.1mb]->[108.1mb]/[108.1mb]}{[old] [3.4gb]->[4.1gb]/[8.9gb]}
```

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: could you add your cluster configuration, your mapping, and as many information as you can, so we can guide you ?

Comment: What cluster configuration do you need? I have provided index mapping.

Comment: how many machines (dedicated to ES?), CPU & RAM

Comment: your indexing rate too. Do you perform aggregations, or only queries ? And are your queries similar ? if so, please provide an example query

Comment: kindly share us the `query` and sample document also. and please change the proper memory args `-Xmx5g -Xms5g` you have min & max as 5g. better to have min as some how minimum value

Comment: @Sarohan it's better to have min & max the same, the JVM then doesn't scale like crazy. Also, if ES is the only thing you're running on the production machine, it's recommended to set the memory to half of the total available RAM (so in this case 8 GB would be optimal).

Comment: @Denis do you use from in your queries to paginate ? And are all your documents in a single index ?

Comment: @juliendangers Yes. I use from=0 and size=10. Yes, all docs in one index, because it's have one type.

Comment: but do you use from=0 then from=10, from=20, ... to get following results ?

Comment: @julendangers No. Only from=0. Maximum - 5. I know about deep paging problem.

Comment: Do you use any monitoring plugin (kopf, head, marvel) ? (btw we should continue on stackoverflow chat to diagnose the problem)

Comment: @julendangers I have installed head and bigdesk plugins. I can make a screenshot with needed information.

Comment: do you add data  to the index constantly ? then when you perform a query, can you check the value of took ? Is it really high ?

Comment: @Denis you do not have enough point to start a conversation, so I suggest we go to IRC on #elasticsearch channel, then we will update the stackoverflow post

Comment: data changed seldom. see jmeter screenshot https://yadi.sk/i/1g9RLsfKgznGm. here 100 concurrent threads straight to elastic.

Comment: @julendangers i connected to irc chanel